# Cannot get into Windows because I get a winlogon.exe error and get BSOD on Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, bsod

So today I was looking at my computer's memory left on the hard disk and it was REALLY low. SO I decided to back all my stuff up onto a portable hard drive and to a system restore from the Symantec Dell restore thing. I did that and wala my computer was completely restored and I was busy updating and downloading all my programs etc... Well I needed to restart for some programs to work so I go to do this. I get onto the log on screen and I get an error saying something cannot be read and it is a winlogon.exe error. It tells me to press cancel to debug or ok to terminate the program. Either one brings me to the infamous BSOD. RN I'm booted onto Ubuntu from a flash drive and I Have access to my hard disk and can see the winlogon.exe. Is there a way to download a clean one and replace them? What can I do :(???

P.S: I would just use Ubuntu but I need Photoshop and iTunes :(

Update:
Hey guys thanks for answering... I don't know why but it seems I can't access the Symantec thing anymore. What you do to get to it on a Dell is hold  and f11. I'll try again but as of now I can't. Also, thanks for your suggestions! I was afraid I would have to redo all of this :( Oh well.

Exact error:
"The instruction at 0x5ad8a69d referenced memory at 0x08e81db6 the memory could not be read"

Answer (score 0):

You have probably destroyed an essential part of Windows.

Restore Windows again from the "Symantec Dell restore thing" (does this mean partition or DVD?).

Then be careful when "busy updating and downloading all my programs etc." not to do that again. Try booting from time to time, so that if this happens again you might at least have a better clue as to what you did by narrowing the field.

Comment: <ctrl> & F11 And it will bring you to a Symantec made WinXP restore or reboot program.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to redo the "Symantec/Dell restore thing". Then first do all the windows updates followed by a restart. Then start installing the software you use.

You'd probably get a better answer than this if you could supply more information about the error that you see. A verbatim copy of "everything" would be best.

Answer (score 0):

I would run a memory tester

http://www.memtest.org/

Download the prebuilt ISO, burn it to CD as an Image (not data), boot from that CD and run the memory test for a couple of hours or overnight to stress test the memory. If you get errors with this test you have a bad memory module, if you have more than one memory module installed remove all but one and re-run the test, test each module individually until you find the bad one.

Comment: How do I burn it from Ubuntu, that's all I have access too :(

Comment: See this...https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto#Ubuntu